# Find a file type and verify a line exists replace if value is different than expected

Tags: replace, exists, verify

I'm trying to write a batch file that will search a directory for a file type. After I find the file name I need to read the file to verify that a line exists and overwrite the line if different than a specific value.

Comment: Please post some code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a unix/linux system, then you can do this:

```
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs -l1 sed -i.bak 's/old contents/new contents/'
```

This will search the current directory (and subdirectories) for files that end with ".txt". For each file it finds, it will look for lines that have "old contents". If it finds such a line, it will replace it with "new contents", and save the old file to its previous name plus ".bak".

If you are on windows, you could install msys or cygwin, and then do the same command.